# Derivative of function of functions

Tags: derivatives

Is this relationship correct? If so, why?

$\frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x)))}{%
\partial g_{1}}\frac{\partial g_{1}(x)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial
f(g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x)))}{\partial g_{2}}\frac{\partial g_{2}(x)}{\partial x}$

Take a function $h(x)$ which can be written as a function $f(\cdot)$ that depends on the functions $g_{1}(x)$ and $g_{2}(x)$, which are sole functions of $x$.

$h(x)=f(g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x))$

I do not make an assumption on the relationship between $g_{1}(x)$ and $g_{1}(x)$ (multiplicative, additive, ...).

Comment: This would be the chain rule...

Comment: In other words yes thats correct, for the reason  copper.hat mentioned

Comment: Thanks. I knew that $\frac{\partial f(g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x)))}{\partial g_{1}}\frac{\partial g_{1}(x)%
}{\partial x}$ follows from the chain rule but I didn't know that this rule also tells you that the relationship for the two $g$-functions is additive regardless of how $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ interact.